# Trying to run postgres on docker. It gives error

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to run postgres on docker with this cmd and It gives error

PS D:\Data Engineering with Zoomcamp>   `docker run -it -e POSTGRES_USER="root" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi"D:\Data Engineering with Zoomcamp\ny_taxi_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres:13`

> docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
> See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: It looks to me like you (or someone whose notes you're following) made a mistake editing the command. Note the lack of space between `"ny_taxi"` and ` D:`

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the volume tag. Use below command

**docker run -it -e POSTGRES_USER="root" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" -v "D:\Data Engineering with Zoomcamp\ny_taxi_postgres":/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres:13**